# What TSQL gives rights to create functions on a schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a program that runs the following sql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [foo\bar].something
(
```

The SQL looks fine, but I get the error

```
The specified schema name "foo\bar" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

What SQL can i run on the database so I get schema access to create a function? I think I want to keep my default schema as dbo and simply have access to this other [foo\bar] schema.

Comment: How do you call the function? Where is the SQL statement that displays the problem? *Does* the `foo/bar` schema even exist?

Comment: I don't exactly know where the sql is called because it is in a program that then gives me the error. The schema exist, but it is not my default schema. I have little knowlege about schemas but I would assume a user can have access to multible I just cant see the help for GRANT what to do.

Comment: *Can* you call the function directly in a SELECT statement?

Comment: function does not get created. I just get the error. I therefore cannot call it

Comment: So what happens when you run the statement `CREATE FUNCTION` directly?? Did you check the syntax of `GRANT`? The `CREATE FUNCTION` privilege is explicitly mentioned. Have you tried a statement that didn't work? What was it and what didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

The SQL Server Books Online states in the CREATE FUNCTION topic (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

> Requires CREATE FUNCTION permission in the database and ALTER
>   permission on the schema in which the function is being created

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason the ALTER did not work in my specific case although I did read the documentation

```
    GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA::[foo\bar] TO [TheUser]
```

Solved it.